Can we set cookies for a WebView in React Native?
I am working on a React Native mobile application which uses a WebView component to load a website in the app. The mobile application implements Google Login and get the JWT token from google and passes it to the WebView with injectJavascript method of WebView. The WebView takes this token and makes the API call to oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?token=<TOKEN>.
Mobile App Method on Login:
  const sendTokenToWebView = token => {
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(`
      (function() {
        window.postMessage(${JSON.stringify(token)}, '*');
      })();
    `);
  };

Web Application:
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleMessage = async (event) => {
            try {
                const token = event.data;
                // login or logout
                if (token === 'logout') {
                    setIsLoggedIn(false);
                    setUserInfo(null);
                }else{
                    // Decode the token
                    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
                    // Use the token to authenticate with Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoint
                    const response = await axios.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo', null, {
                        params: {
                            id_token: token,
                        },
                    });

                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        setIsLoggedIn(true);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to validate token with Google:', response.status);
                    }
                }


            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error decoding token or validating with Google:', error);
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
        };
    }, []);

Now when I use the Google Login in the web app independently using web client ID, it sets the cookies in the browser but not when I am using the webview. I hope the problem is clear. I want to set cookies in the WebView so that any API requests it sends to backend server are with cookies.
